# How to Migrate ORM Grendao to ORM Sugar in Android MySQLite, if possible?

Tags: android, android-studio, orm

I have an Android Application, built with Android Studio, using CRUD function with Grendao ORM. However, I would like to migrate to ORM Sugar. How to change that ORM? or do I need to change full code in Integrated from Grendao ORM to Sugar ORM?

Comment: Why are u migrating to Sugar ORM, Green dao is the best...I think you can use same Table entities for Sugar orm with an addition off @Table annotation.

Comment: Why i change the ORM, i have a problem, to get result insert with new line "/n" my input does't work to get down input .... how to fix that Adding "Enter" to query in GreenDao ORM ? .... i'm create Application like Barcode in Inventory ,, Using Greendao ...